# GAN Minibatch Discrimination Pytorch Implementation

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am attempting to implement minibatch discrimination for a DCGAN to combat modal collapse. I have tried to understand the methods described in [text](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03498v1.pdf) Improved Techniques for Training GANs, Salimans et al., 2016.

From the paper, it was not entirely clear how the authors chose the transformation tensor "T." What is its shape and contents?

Regardless, I went ahead and tried to implement the MB discrimination method in the following module:

```
# Input Shape: (batchsize,in_features)
class Minibatch(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_features,out_features,kernel=1) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.in_features=in_features
        self.out_features=out_features
        self.kernel = kernel

        # Transformation matrix : (kernel,in_features,out_features)
        self.T = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((kernel,in_features,out_features)))

    def forward(self,input):
        x = input

        # Multiply Input by Transformation Matrix: (kernel,batchsize,out_features)
        x = torch.matmul(input,self.T)

        # cb(xi,xj) -> exp(-L1 norm (Mi,b-Mj,b)) : (kerel,batchsize,out_features)
        x = torch.exp(-torch.abs((x.unsqueeze(1)-x.unsqueeze(2))).sum(dim=1))

        # Sum of cb(xi,xj) : (batchsize,out_features)
        x = x.sum(dim=0)

        # Concatenate with original input
        x = torch.cat((input,x),dim=1)
        return x
```

Running some sample data through the module:

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
M = Minibatch(4,1)
A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,4],[2,2,5,4]]).to(torch.float32)/5
B = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]).to(torch.float32)
C = torch.randn((3,4))

M(A)[:,-1][:].detach(),M(B)[:,-1].detach(),M(C)[:,-1].detach()
```

```
Outputs:
tensor(\[0.2382, 0.3074, 0.4183\]),
tensor(\[1., 1., 1.\]),
tensor(\[0.0111, 0.0886, 0.0626\])
```

This seems like plausible output. The batch with identical values returned 1s for all samples in the batch. The batch with random values returns "near zero" output, and the batch with some matching values returns something between [0,1].

However, if I scale up the module to an input feature size of 1000--a more reasonable output from an intermediate layer in the discriminator--the outputs no longer make sense to me.

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
M1000 = Minibatch(1000,1)
D = torch.randn(3,1000)
E = torch.tensor([np.arange(0,1000),np.arange(0,1000),np.arange(0,1000)])/1000
E[0,100] = 1
M1000(D)[:,-1].detach(),M1000(E)[:,-1].detach()
```

```
Outputs:
tensor(\[4.2177e-31, 3.1751e-31, 5.1161e-21\]),
tensor(\[0.0091, 0.0952, 0.0952\])
```

D makes sense. The "similarity index" of a randomly distributed [0,1] vector of length 1000 should in theory be zero. E however, is a 3x1000 batch of identical values between [0,1] with a single value changed from 0.1 -> 1.0. I would expect this to yield a near perfect similarity index of 1, but instead returns a near zero index.